# Invalid image reference registry when using jib to dockerize gradle project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jib

I had a problem when dockerize the Gradle project.
running ***gradle jib***

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':jib'.

> Invalid image reference registry.hub.docker.com/myusername/${rootProject.name}, perhaps you should check that the reference is formatted correctly according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description
> For example, slash-separated name components cannot have uppercase letters

**Root Module**

setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'myproject'
include 'discovery-service'
include 'client-service'
include 'notification-service'
include 'api-gateway'
```

build.gradle

```
jib {
    var tag = 'latest'
    from {
        image = 'eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre'
    }
    to {
        image = 'registry.hub.docker.com/myUsername/${rootProject.name}'
    }
}
```

One of the service

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.leekify'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'client-service'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
....
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'client-service'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quotes instead of single quotes for the `jib.to.image` string so that Gradle evaluates the variable.